# Java MouseEvents not working

Tags: java, swing, awt, mouseevent, mouseenter

This may be a stupid question, but I have to ask!

I have the following code snippets that are supposed to run their corresponding methods when the user interacts with objects.
For some reason, "foo" is never printed, but "bar" is.

```
myJSpinner1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    System.out.println("foo"); //"foo" is not printed
  }
});

myJSpinner2.addChangeListener(new java.awt.event.ChangeListener() {
    public void stateChanged(java.awt.event.ChangeEvent evt) {
    System.out.println("bar"); //"bar" is printed
  }
});
```

I get no exceptions or stack trace. What am I missing in the MouseListener one?
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** MouseEntered works perfectly on a JCheckBox implemented in exactly the same way!

Comment: I realise this explanation is a little sparse. Please ask if you need an extra information. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JSpinner` is a composite component consisting of a text field and 2 buttons. It's possible to add mouse listeners to all of those by iterating over the results of `getComponents()` and adding a listener to each.

However, in my experience, when something takes that much work, you're probably going about it the wrong way.

Why do you need the mouse-entered information for a `JSpinner`?
What do you want to do with this event?

**Update:**
If you're looking to supply information about all of the controls in your panel, you may want to look at using a glasspane to detect the component under the mouse.

[A Well-behaved Glasspane](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2006/09/20/well-behaved-glasspane) by Alexander Potochkin is a good place to start.

Comment: I have another component in which I want to display text which explains what the spinner does. Like a statusbar, I suppose!

Comment: Perhaps consider using a tooltip instead of showing the function in the status bar?

Comment: I had considered that, but I need to use tooltips elsewhere for other reasons and for the sake on consistency, I'l rather use this. 

Surely this is something stupid that I've missed out? I can't see why it would work on other components and not spinners?

Comment: Iterating over the results of getComponents() works, but only for the buttons, not the text field! Weird, but it'll have to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is a guess but I suspect you need to add a `MouseListener` to the `JSpinner`'s editor (via a call to `getEditor()`).  I imagine that the editor `Component` occupies all available space within the `JSpinner` and is therefore intercepting all `MouseEvent`s.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is this what you mean? senseSpinner.getEditor().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){...})' That doesn't seem to work either. The funny thing is, this code was generated using NetBeans and so in theory, should work!

Comment: Yes that's what I meant.  Actually, you could try adding the listener to the editor's text field by calling ((JSpinner.DefaultEditor)spinner.getEditor()).getTextField().addMouseListener(...).

Comment: Nope, same thing happens. Namely, nothing!

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

```
JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner();

((JSpinner.DefaultEditor)spinner.getEditor()).getTextField().addMouseListener(
    new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {            
    public void mouseClicked(final MouseEvent e) {   
        // add code here
    }
});
```

I needed this in order to evoke a popup key dialog for added usability due to our software requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Aditional to @Rapier answer...

If you change the Spinner using something like

```
yourOldSpinner = new JSpinner(new SpinnerModel(...))
```

you will lost your previosly MouseListener...

If you need to change something of `SpinnerModel`, Don't create a new, change its parameters instead! (if you do it, you will need to reassign the MouseListener again, because it will be lost when you assign a new SpinnerModel).

an example (I'm talking...):

```
((SpinnerNumberModel)yourOldSpinner.getModel()).setValue(size/3);
((SpinnerNumberModel)yourOldSpinner.getModel()).setMinimum(0);
((SpinnerNumberModel)yourOldSpinner.getModel()).setMaximum(isize/2);
((SpinnerNumberModel)yourOldSpinner.getModel()).setStepSize(1);
```