# JSpinner ActionListener alternative

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, awt

In my program, I want to use a JSpinner for a number. This number will later be used to calculate something. Every time the user clicks one of the spinner buttons (up or down), I want the result to update automatically. Since you can't add an ActionListener to a JSpinner (which I think is really weird), I am asking here how to do something similar to this (I already have an ActionListener ready for this, which can be changed in any other listener of course).

Comment: Your answer might be this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2553401/2319378

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could add a [`ChangeListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ChangeListener.html) to the spinner. This will be triggered by the button presses (or a direct edit of the field).

```
spinner.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {      
  @Override
  public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
    // handle click
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

> Every time the user clicks one of the spinner button (up or down), I want the result to update automatically.

Add a `DocumentListener` to the `Document` of the text field that is being used as the editor of the spinner.

Edit:

```
JSpinner.DefaultEditor editor = (JSpinner.DefaultEditor)number.getEditor();
JTextField textField = editor.getTextField();
textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener( new DocumentListener()
{
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println("insert");
    }

    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println("remove");
    }

    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {}
});
```

Comment: Like this?
`((JSpinner.DefaultEditor)spinner.getEditor()).getTextField().getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {...}`
It doesn't seem to work...

Comment: @Creator13, yes, that is the general code. Works fine for me. Although the ChangeListener is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only way I've found:

```
for (Component c : mySpinner.getComponents()) {
    if (c instanceof JButton) {
        ((JButton) c).addActionListener(...);
    }
    if (c instanceof JSpinner.DefaultEditor) {
        ((JSpinner.DefaultEditor) c).getTextField().addActionListener(...);
    }
}
```